# CMake variables error when installing faiss-gpu: "Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture"

Tags: cmake, dockerfile, faiss

I’m order to install faiss-gpu, I first needed to install cmake and did it by cloning the cmake repo from github.com/Kitware/CMake and running

`./bootstrap && make && make install`

Then to install faiss-gpu I cloned the following repo guthub.com/facebookresearch/faiss Once cloned I changed directory into that folder and ran the following:

`cmake -B build . && make -C -j faiss`

But I get multiple errors related to environment variables not set such as:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:603 (message):
  Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture.
 
 
 
  Compiler output:
 
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:62 (enable_language)
 
 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

After doing some research I found this as a possible solution, so I did the following:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=52 61 -DTARGET_NAME=tgt
```

Then the next error is that there is a missing variable: _CMAKE_CUDA_WHOLE_FLAG

Read above as described in detail.

Comment: Read the error message. It's not about environment variables not being set.

Comment: @Friedrich what is the error related to? Everything I found online seems to suggest that’s the case